# Trying to replace document.write to a innerHTML but it doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm making code for an assignment where I have to make a for loop multiplication table with input variables I've gotten the table to work but I want to input it specifically into a`<div id='buffer'></div>` and not just using a `'document.write'`.

```
var _buffer = document.getElementById('buffer');
var rows=prompt("enter rows");
var columns=prompt('enter columns');
document.write("<table border='1'>");
for (var a=1; a < rows ; a++) {
    document.write("<tr>");
    for(var b=1; b< columns; b++) {
        document.write("<td>"+a*b+"</td>");
    }
    document.write("</tr>");
}
document.write("</table>");
```

I want to use a `_buffer.innerHTML` instead of the `document.write` but when I change out the the code it doesn't print the information in a table so I was looking for help and suggestions thanks!

Comment: Maybe you should show what you have so far (e.g. your try without `document.write`).

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize the variable (`t` in the example below), and put all that text into that string, then assign it to `innerHTML`:

```
var _buffer = document.getElementById('buffer');
var rows=prompt("enter rows");
var columns=prompt('enter columns');

var t = "<table border='1'>";
for (var a=1; a < rows ; a++) {
    t = t + "<tr>";
    for(var b=1; b< columns; b++) {
        t = t + "<td>"+a*b+"</td>";
    }
    t = t + "</tr>";
}
t = t + "</table>";

_buffer.innerHTML = t;
```

Comment: Great! If that solves your problem, please accept my answer.